Issue with asynchronous logging using Logback on Tomcat
I'm currently facing an issue with logging configuration in my Java web application deployed on Tomcat. I'm using Logback as the logging framework and have configured a ConsoleAppender with <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush> to ensure synchronous logging to the console.
Despite these configurations, logs are still being written asynchronously or with noticeable delay in the console. I've reviewed and adjusted my logback.xml configuration, checked logging dependencies in my pom.xml, and restarted Tomcat multiple times after each configuration change.
Could you please verify if this configuration appears correct for achieving synchronous logging without delay in the console? Are there any specific JVM parameters or Tomcat configurations that I should adjust to resolve this issue?
<configuration> 
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
        <encoder> 
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern> 
            <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush> 
        </encoder> 
    </appender> 
    <root level="info"> 
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
    </root> 
</configuration>





%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
true


<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>


Just for future reference, see formatting help. You can also take the [tour], read [ask] and browse other [help] topics.
